# Apache Spark Structured Streaming + Kafka - Attempt to send response via channel for which there is no connection

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am using Spark Structured Streaming (2.3.0) with Kafka (1.0.0).

```
val event_stream: DataStreamReader = spark
  .readStream
  .format(_source)
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", _brokers)
  .option("subscribe", topic)
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
```

I am testing the pipeline with 100 G of data for one Kafka topic. On the Kafka broker (3 bootstrap nodes with 2G heap/ 4G RAM each) I see this WARN message on a very frequent basis(almost every second):

```
WARN Attempting to send response via channel for which there is no open connection, connection id 10.230.0.81:9092-10.230.0.116:39110-399 (kafka.network.Processor)
```

I also see that the Heap consumption on the broker steadily increases to a point where % time in GC becomes close to 100 (without much memory release) causing an OOM and node-crash.
Using the below options:

```
-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

and also tried Replace `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC with -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent` based on [KAFKA-5470](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5470)

My rate of production of messages is around 7k messages/s (1 KB message).

I know we are not really pushing Kafka to its limits. Yet it's a surprise that the OOM events and subsequent node crashes happen.

I would appreciate notes/comments/inputs from folks who have experienced these issues and have insights into this area.

**EDIT:**

Tried with confluent recommended [params](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/deployment.html) and I still observe the  problems as described above:

```
-Xms6g -Xmx6g -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20
       -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M
       -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80
```

I wonder if there is a leak in Spark Kafka (structured streaming) integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to simply post an update here:

The OOM was a result of an unclosed producer (not related to Spark) and we were able to track and fix it.

However, the warning message is still visible in Kafka. But it doesn't cause any production issue (that we know of)

`WARN Attempting to send response via channel for which there is no open connection, connection id 10.230.0.81:9092-10.230.0.116:39110-399 (kafka.network.Processor)`